# Azure Devops Service Now - how to get CHANGE_REQUEST_NUMBER/CHANGE_CORRELATION_ID for YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, servicenow, azure-pipelines-yaml, servicenow-rest-api

Following the MS documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/servicenow?view=azure-devops

I've set up an Azure DevOps environment with the Service Now Pre-deployment check and can successfully create a new standard change request in Service Now and update it using the UpdateServiceNowChangeRequest@2 task.

However, I'm struggling to find a way to access the CHANGE_REQUEST_NUMBER and CHANGE_CORRELATION_ID that are available to the UpdateServiceNowChangeRequest@2 tasks

The documentation describes how to get to these using the release pipeline by having a name for the gate and using $(PREDEPLOYGATE.mygatename.CHANGE_REQUEST_NUMBER), but there is no option in the YAML setup to name a gate and I can't seem to find another way to get to these variables

I've tried just enumerating all the environment variables in the pwsh task (i.e. gci env:\ ) but nothing relating to these variables shows up.